# Can I distribute iOS apps with a QR code without having a developers account and acquired certificate?

Tags: ios, cordova, dreamweaver, qr-code, phonegap-build

I am making an app with Dreamweaver and PhoneGap but I find the whole distribution to iOS process pretty messed up. I am doing the app as a project for a festival that my university course is putting together. My general intention was to distribute the app using a QR code, however I recently found out that I would still need an Apple developers account, as well as a certificate, in order to make the app downloadable to iOS devices. I thought the whole point of QR was not having to pay $99 and going through the whole "approval" process. See, I can't afford such an account myself so I need to find a way to distribute to iOS without one.

This topic may seem pretty stupid to you but please note that I am new at this and I am in the process of learning code by myself so I really need your advice right now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No. You can't install apps on ANY iOS device unless you pay $99 to become a member of Apple's developer program. There is no way around this (excluding jailbroken devices.)

Apple's Xcode development software is free, and lets you build and run software on the simulator, but not on devices.

A QR code is just a number encoded into a graphical symbol. It doesn't have any magical ability to install software. People often encode URLs into QR codes, and many QR readers recognize a URL encoded into a QR code and open the URL automatically. If that URL happens to point to an app in the Apple app store, or to a site like TestFlight that can install apps over the air, then it can serve as a link to a place where users can install apps, but those apps must be built by an Apple-licensed iOS developer who's paid the $99 fee.

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not allow the distribution of applications that have not been created with a development certificate.

PhoneGap exists to allow the building applications using web technologies instead of native programming. It is not the intention of PhoneGap to allow subversion of Apple's application approvals.

To distribute your app you will need to get a dev license and submit your app for approval through Apple.

In some cases you can apply for a Enterprise license that allows you to distribute to multiple devices without being obtained through iTunes, but this costly and only for corporations to distribute internal applications.

QR codes have nothing to do with this process. If you had a valid app in iTunes you could give out a QR code that contains the link to the apps page, allowing people to find your app in the store easier.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard of distributing an app via QR code and perhaps it's something to do with Dreamweaver/Phonegap. The only way I could see it working would be to point the user to the App Store location via a link contained in the QR code to purchase/download the app there.

To even get the app running on your own device, provided you don't plan to restrict this to jailbreakers, you'll need to have an Apple Developer account. It's a barrier to entry into this market, but it's part of the process.

Once you're set up with that, the approval process isn't that troublesome, given that you're playing by the fairly straightforward rules that Apple provides as part of the program.

I hope you do find a way to get the app distributed out, but I think it may require paying for the developer account to get there. Good luck!

Comment: What a shame. Thank you for explaining though :)